# Java android BaseAdapter - how do I setText in a TextView at particular position from adapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I probably can't formulate a right search query for google to solve my question.

I have a ListView adapter extending BaseAdapter where each position have some views in it.

One of them is a TextView by clicking which I start DatePicker dialog. So, by having a result set on it I need to `setText()` back on the TextView I clicked. How do I set this text to exact position I clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On item clickEvent get the `TextView` and save this in a local variable. Now in the date set listener get the date and set this to the `TextView` Achieved from the saved local `View`.

```
TextView currentSelection;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {
        currentSelection = (TextView)view;
    }
});
```

Comment: Greatly thanx! and how can I later getText() from all the positions (I got textViews and EditTexts in each position) when I need to keep (or send) data?

Comment: You can save it inside an ArrayList or Array based on position